# go to another Qtab on button click

Tags: c++, qt

hello I have made this little project and I would like to know how I can switch tabs when I click on a button.

I have already tried this :

```
  void Widget::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
  {
       ui->Menu->setCurrentWidget (ui->parametres);
  }
```

but it doesn't work.
I would apreciate any help.

Comment: Do you using QTabWidget?

Comment: @SimMak yes I'm using it

Comment: Try to set this property of your QTabWIdget instance. 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop

Comment: Could you please tell me, what type is ui->Menu? Also ui->parameters look so suspicious, cause tab of your widget should be accessible, though parent.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html), when you use [`addTab()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#addTab) function, it returns the index of the tab. So, you can easily use [`setCurrentIndex(int index)`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) by passing the value you saved from the first function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already make the signal/slot connection?
`connect(pushButton3, &QPushButton::clicked, [&] () { ui-->Menu->setcurrentWidget(ui->parametres); });`

Or try setcurrentindex (index) like Mohammed suggested but the connect statement has to be made.